# Deploy an image in a feature

Tags: development, visual-studio, feature, image-display

I am creating a feature which adds an option to the ECB. I want to have a custom icon/image. In my Visual Studio 2010 project I have created a TEMPLATE/IMAGES/proj folders. I have added my image to the folder.

I have deployed my feature from VS2010 but the image is not in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES\proj.

When I double click on the feature the image is not listed under files but I don't seem able to add it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need to create SharePoint Mapped Folder (this is not a simple project folder):

[image]